# Observable find nested property

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

An Observable return this object

```
[
  {
    "args": { },
    "output": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Sparrow",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Davy ",
        "lastName": "Jones",
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Is there a way using `RxJx` operators to return the element of `output` array where `id===2`? So to get only this:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Davy ",
  "lastName": "Jones",
}
```

I think I should use `find`, although can't find an example of usage with nested objects.

My current code (I know that `find` part isn't correct):

```
  public getUserData(id: number) {
    this.http.get<any>(URL)
      .pipe(
         find(element => element.output)
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res)
     })
  }
```

Comment: but isnt find the same as filter but breaking after first true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a combination of `mergeMap` (often called `flatMap` in other **Rx** implementations) and `filter`!

`mergeMap` allows you to:

1. **map** each of your items into *lists* (that is, emit a list of values for each event)
2. **flatten** the lists together back into *one stream of events*

... which you then `filter` in order to keep only the ones who match the predicate of your choice (in your case: `output => output.id === 2`).

---

You can play with the code snippet below where you can edit yourself the response you receive and click on the corresponding button to trigger the event.

```js
const data = [{
  "args": {},
  "output": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Jack",
      "lastName": "Sparrow",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Davy ",
      "lastName": "Jones",
    }
  ],
}];

const textarea = document.querySelector('#data-source');
const button = document.querySelector('#trigger-response');

// Assume `myObservable comes from the result of an Ajax request`
const myObservable = rxjs
  .fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .pipe(rxjs.operators.map(() => JSON.parse(textarea.value.replace(/,(?=\s*\})/mg, ''))));

myObservable.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.mergeMap(response => response[0].output),
  rxjs.operators.filter(output => output.id === '2')
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

textarea {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="data-source" rows="20">[
  {
    "args": { },
    "output": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Sparrow",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Davy ",
        "lastName": "Jones",
      }
    ],
  }
]</textarea>
<button id="trigger-response">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like this:

```js
this.http.get<any>(URL)
    .pipe(
        mergeAll(), // flatten the root array
        mergeMap(item => item.output), // flatten the output array
        filter(output => output.id === '2')
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res); // Tahdah!!
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care not about the emission from the observables (for example how frequent they are emitted), you can just use `filter` from [native Javascript Array Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and **not** the [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) from the Observables. Fundamentally they are different, but unless you have any strong reasons to use the Observable one you can just use the array one. The code is much shorter and more performant:

```
public getUserData(id: number) {
    this.http.get<any>(URL)
        .map(data => data.output.filter(x => x.id === '2'))
}
```

In fact, for your case, if you are **SURE** to filter by `id`, which is assumed to be unique, you can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) using `es6` syntax. It will return you the first element of the condition met:

```
public getUserData(id: number) {
    this.http.get<any>(URL)
        .map(data => data.output.find(x => x.id === '2'))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter:

```
public getUserData(id: number) {
  this.http.get<any>(URL)
  .pipe(
     filter(element => {
       for (let output of element.output){
           return output.id === "2";
       }
     })
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res)
  })
}
```